# Display message at a specific location in Google Maps Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How can I display a message at a specific location in a Google Maps Activity on Android without adding a marker? I just want to display a small pop up animation containing a message at specific coordinates.

Are there any GitHub libraries that can perform this specific task?

Answer (score 5):

You can place any `View` over `MapFragment` (or `MapView`) and animate it as you wish with [Animations](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview): animate size, position, transparency etc., use various [interpolators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator) and merge several animations into one via [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet). To get screen position of the `View` for specific `LatLng` coordinates you can use [`Projection.toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) method.

For example, for "Hello World" `TextView` with "popup" animation over the map, you can use code like that:

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activities.MainActivity">

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapSupportedFragment;

    private TextView mPopUpTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPopUpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popup_view);

        mMapSupportedFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapSupportedFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                // get screen position for latLng
                Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
                Point origin = projection.toScreenLocation(latLng);

                // popup TextView
                popUpView(origin, mPopUpTextView, 500);
            }
        });
    }

    public void popUpView(final Point origin, final View view, long duration){
        view.setX(origin.x);
        view.setY(origin.y);

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ValueAnimator sizeAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.getMeasuredHeight());
        sizeAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        sizeAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        sizeAnimation.setDuration(duration);

        ValueAnimator positionAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.getMeasuredHeight());
        positionAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        positionAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                view.setY(origin.y - val);
            }
        });
        positionAnimation.setDuration(duration);

        AnimatorSet popUpSet = new AnimatorSet();
        popUpSet.play(sizeAnimation).with(positionAnimation);
        popUpSet.start();

    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Popup message]

Comment: This is good, and I already knew of this possiblity. However, I want a more polished version of this for a professional company app. That's why I initially asked for a library. Having a plain TextView is not enough.

Comment: @user8618899 You can use any view (or Layout) instead of `TextView` for `popUpView()` method.

Comment: What would be the most pleasing to the eye option?

Comment: @user8618899 It depends. IMHO I'd use a custom view for complex layout or `TextView` with `html` (like [this](https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2017/09/29/android-html-textview/)) or spannable rich formatting (like [that](https://medium.com/@Cuong.Le/android-rich-text-overview-397e6af529d9)). Or even use `ImageView` with programmatically generated Bitmap...

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you go with marker only.
As marker it self gives some features like animation and all.

You can also customize the marker in different way to show the text and not the image and also you can user the customized text like html text show more decorated text backed by html and css.

This one is simple and great solution as i have also used the same in of my project.